# Why is WInJS included automatically when targeting Windows 8 in Cordova?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova, winjs

We're developing an app using AngularJS, and when we're targeting Windows 8 I noticed that the generated Visual Studio project included WinJS as a reference. Since we're not using WinJS I simply removed the reference from the project.

Then I noticed that removing WinJS caused benign script load errors in the console when running the app. Further investigation showed that [cordova.js](https://github.com/apache/cordova-windows/blob/master/template/www/cordova.js) automatically checks for WinJS, and if not included tries to include it (!). Here's the relevant code:

```
var onWinJSReady = function () {
    var app = WinJS.Application;
    var checkpointHandler = function checkpointHandler() {
        cordova.fireDocumentEvent('pause',null,true);
    };

    var resumingHandler = function resumingHandler() {
        cordova.fireDocumentEvent('resume',null,true);
    };

    app.addEventListener("checkpoint", checkpointHandler);
    Windows.UI.WebUI.WebUIApplication.addEventListener("resuming", resumingHandler, false);
    app.start();
};

if (!window.WinJS) {
    var scriptElem = document.createElement("script");

    if (navigator.appVersion.indexOf("Windows Phone 8.1;") !== -1) {
        // windows phone 8.1 + Mobile IE 11
        scriptElem.src = "//Microsoft.Phone.WinJS.2.1/js/base.js";
    } else if (navigator.appVersion.indexOf("MSAppHost/2.0;") !== -1) {
        // windows 8.1 + IE 11
        scriptElem.src = "//Microsoft.WinJS.2.0/js/base.js";
    } else {
        // windows 8.0 + IE 10
        scriptElem.src = "//Microsoft.WinJS.1.0/js/base.js";
    }
    scriptElem.addEventListener("load", onWinJSReady);
    document.head.appendChild(scriptElem);
}
else {
    onWinJSReady();
}
```

I guess my main question is, **should I just leave the WinJS reference "as is" and let Cordova load and initialize WinJS?**

Could it potentially conflict with AngularJS or reduce the performance of the app in any way?
(I guess `var app = WinJS.Application` and `app.start()` in `onWinJSReady` makes me a bit worried).

Since the app seems to work fine without the WinJS script files, why is cordova.js so insistent on trying to include it?

Answer (score 2):

cordova (and some cordova plugins, particularly the FileSystem plugin) use some features of WinJS, such as Promises and Ajax calls.  We ended up forking cordova.js and stripping out all the WinJS stuff... makes the app load a lot faster!

Comment: Thanks. So it sounds like my worry was a bit warranted, that it actually *does* add some bloat to the app. Since some plugins might rely on WinJS it might just be easiest to leave it alone.

Comment: Have you run into any other side effects from doing so?

Comment: @chinabuffet nope, pages are faster to load, compiled app is (a little bit) smaller

Comment: @EionRobb how did you strip out all the WinJS stuff? I really don't need any `WinJS` in my `react` cordova app.

Comment: @philk just by editing cordova.js, removed any references to WinJS and added in a very small promise library, promiscuous, instead. We are running a fairly old version of cordova though, which still has all the core plugins.